# Is possible to replace an expression with a text in PHP?

Tags: php

For exemple, it's possible to replace

```
{'a1b2,left'}
```

with

```
<img src="a1b2" class="left"/>
```

in Php?

Comment: yes its possible , check [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: regular expressions are not my best :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes...

```
$str = preg_replace('/\{\'(.*?),(.*?)\'\}/', '<img src="$1" class="$2"/>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

```
//strip unwanted characters.
$string = preg_replace("/[{'}]/", "", $string);
//convert string to array
$string = explode(',', $string); 
<img src="<?php echo $string[0]; ?>" class="<?php echo $string[1]; ?>"/>
```

Comment: alex have posted the better solution, so you should probably go with his solution